# How to turn a folder hierarchy into a share on one server and copy permissions from a different server?

Tags: powershell, networking, system-administration, file-sharing

Server 1 is going to be going away which is currently our file sharing server. Server 2 is going to be replacing Server 1. Right now Server 2 has the same folder structure and files already added to it, but none of it is setup as a share. Is their a way I can turn all folders on Server 1 into a share, copy the permissions from those folders on Server 2 and add them to the shares on Server 1. For example:

Server 1 has file structure dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt. 
Server 2 will have the same exact file structure dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt

I need to turn Server 2 files into a share then copy permissions from each directory/file on Server 1 and add them to the counterparts on Server 2. I would prefer this to be programmatically as we have a lot of different shares/directories. I tried using Get-Acl and Set-Acl, but it only does it folder per call. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: There is a script in the [Gallery](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Migrate-Share-Permissions-eb9e9ec4) to get and set share permissions. Have a look.

Comment: [Maybe related](https://www.loginconsultants.com/de/news/tipps-tricks/item/migrating-a-file-server). I'd argue that [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) is a more suitable place for this question, though.

Comment: take a look at robocopy. it has the ability to copy over permissions, i think.